# hive showing null value

Tags: hive, hdfs

I'm trying to get my `hdfs` data in hive but it shows NULL value.

Here is the sequence of commands that I'm executing

```
hive> LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/hadoop/oriondemo/data/Floor1_Floor/Floor1_Floor.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE new;
Loading data to table default.new
OK
Time taken: 0.538 seconds
hive> select * from new;
OK
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
Time taken: 0.321 seconds, Fetched: 5 row(s)
hive>
```

Comment: Please provide any sample data in the text file and schema of the hive table which you created.This might help solve your issue.

Comment: if you are able to run `select` on that table means table exist. just provide file content and table DDL

Comment: Could you please do Show create table <table name> and check the rows delimited by which <delimiter>? and then check if the input file has the same delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

what is the column separator you are using to upload this text file ? if it is comma(,) then check the values, might be some values can have additional comma for e.g. values of address column.